# Trouble searching a string for words python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
u'>>\n> yes\n>'
```

and the following function, to search it for yes or y:

```
def checkformatch(search_str):    

    to_find = re.compile(r'\b(yes|y)\b')
    match_obj = to_find.search(search_str.lower)
    which_word_matched = match_obj.group() if match_obj else ''
    return which_word_matched
```

as far as I can tell nothing is being returned. When I step through this in the pycharm debugger, it doesn't seem to get to the return statement ( very strange behaviour ).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your actual code have an exception handler? Because `match_obj = to_find.search(search_str.lower)` should raise the exception: `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: By compiling your regex each time you call your function, you are entirely defeating the purpose of compiling it.

Comment: what do you suggest (I'm not knowledgeable about regex) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code throws a `TypeError: expected string or buffer` on a `match_obj = to_find.search(search_str.lower)` line.

`lower()` [is a method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), you need to call it:

```
to_find.search(search_str.lower())
```

Comment: Or make the regex case insensitive - `re.compile(r'\b(yes|y)\b', re.IGNORECASE)`